# Cater for Angular form that has empty value

Tags: angular

I have the following form initializing method. I am trying to cater for when there is no email value i.e there is no email value coming through from api. Currently I get the following error: *ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined*

```
  private initForm() {
    this._userService.getCurrentUserProfileData()
      .subscribe((user) => {
        this.userReady = user;
        console.log(this.userReady);
        this.userFormGroup = new FormGroup({
          firstName: new FormControl(this.userReady.firstname, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]*$')]),
          lastName: new FormControl(this.userReady.lastname, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]*$')]),
          email: new FormControl(this.userReady.corporateContactChannels[0].value, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
          mobile: new FormControl(this.userReady.corporateContactChannels[1].value, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]),
          workNumber: new FormControl(this.userReady.corporateContactChannels[2].value, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]),
          role: new FormControl({value: this.storeService.setStoreData().profile.role, disabled: true} , Validators.required)
        });
      }, (error) => {
        this._errorService.openErrorPopup('Failed to get profile data.');
      }
    );
  }
```

I have tried an *ngIf on the html form but it seems to be breaking on the email line in the ts file. Anything I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
this.userReady.corporateContactChannels[0].value
```

with

```
this.userReady.corporateContactChannels[0] 
  ? this.userReady.corporateContactChannels[0].value 
  : ''; // or whatever default value you want to use
```

The only other item of note is you are using indexes which have positional significance, I hope these are preserved/respected if undefined values are included from the api.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to avoid it, do something like:

```js
this.userFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  ...
  email: new FormControl(
            this.userReady && this.userReady.corporateContactChannels[0] 
              ? this.userReady.corporateContactChannels[0].value 
              : null, 
            [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  mobile: ...
});
```